# Celery task not waiting for database updates

Tags: django, celery, django-channels

Can someone explain why I can't get the updated database records in the Celery task_success signal?

#consumers.py

```
@database_sync_to_async
def save_to_db(game)
    Result.objects.create(game=game)

class GameConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    ...
    async def save_result(self, event):    
        await save_to_db(self.game)
```

#tasks.py

```
@shared_task(name="run_game")
def run_game():
    ...
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'game',
            {
                'type': 'save.result'
            }
        )

    return(game)

@task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=run_game, result=None, **kwargs):
    game_results = Game.objects.get(id=result.id).results.all()

    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        'game',
        {
            'type': 'end.game',
            'data': game_results 
        }
```