# How to await a channel_layer.group_send (with @database_sync_to_async) inside a Celery shared_task?

Tags: django, celery, django-channels

I have a **AsyncWebsocketConsumer** where one method uses @**database_sync_to_async**
to save the connected user data to the database.

Now I want to call this from outside (in a celery **shared_task**) via **channel_layer.group_send**.

But how can I wait for **all** the connected users db-operations to go through before continuing the task?

Later in the shared_task I want to get all the updated db-records and brodcast it to the same group.

I thought a **async_to_sync** wrapping the **channel_layer.group_send** would do this. But it sends immediately before all db-operations is done.

(A work around is by putting a **time.sleep(8)** in between but I don't like this approach because
I really dont know how long exactly it would take.)

Comment: _"But how can I wait for all the connected users db-operations to go through before continuing the task?"_

How are you performing those other db operations after saving the connected user to the database? Are you using another @database_sync_to_async function and awaiting that in your consumer method?

Comment: @oktested No, I want to do it straight in the Celery task and just send the db-result to a consumer. First I want to call a consumer that saves down every connceted user game result with database_sync_to_async . Then I want to get a list of finished results and send to a consumer. The problem is it sends it before all results are saved..

Comment: Might be easier to understand this if you put your code here. consumer with the group_send, the @database function, and the celery functions to send finished results.

Comment: @oktested Ok, maybe this makes it more clear what im trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647763/celery-task-not-waiting-for-database-updates